# Symfony 4, access to public/index.php OK in dev mode, access KO (404) in prod mode

Tags: symfony, symfony4, production-environment

In development mode, I use an apache server, I go to my App via `localhost/myApp/public/index.php` . I want test prod mod with my symfony 4 application.

- I changed the APP_ENV variable to "prod" (in the .env file)
- I installed composer packages via the command `composer install --no-dev`

But now, when I open my browser and go to `localhost/myApp/public/index.php`, I get a symfony 404 error page :

[image]

The apache configuratin seems good (I can access to the website without any problems in dev mode and I get a 404 not found built by symfony, the index.php is found by apache). I don't understand where may be the problem :/

EDIT : below, the content of the .htaccess file (in the public directory). I don't modify it, this is the symfony default htaccess file :

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Edit 3 : I created the php file `foo.php` in the dir public with `<?php echo 'foo';?>` and I can access to this file through my browser without any problem. Something is wrong with symfony but impossible to find where is my error...

Thank you for any help !

Comment: any logs? look into the files around `var/logs/prod.yml`

Comment: in the var/log I have 3 files `dev.log`, `prod.deprecations.log` and `prod.log`. And no one file is changed when I go to `localhost/myapp/public`. (in `/var/log/apache2/` , only the file `access.log` change)

Comment: Did you install the [htaccess](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules) file? Normally, in production, I would expect a vhost to be used but it has been sometime since I have had the pleasure of using apache.

Comment: I'm not a great htaccess expert. But I see a .htaccess file in the public directory and I don't modify it. I'll edit my post for show the content of this htaccess file.

Comment: have you `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`?

Comment: thanks for help all :) I just run the command `./bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` but the 404 page stays :/

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid. In dev mode, the home page ('/') doesn't show a 404 but a page generated automatically by symfony.

The reason of why I have a 404 in prod mode is I don't create a controller with a route for the path '/'.

So, this 404 in home page in prod env is just logical